# How can I show a random image (generated with captcha) in kivy part?

Tags: python, kivy, captcha, kivymd

I want everytime, with random module, create a new source to the image, to not show everytime the same image. I change the source everytime an image is generated. The source of the image is the same of text contained in this image. But it always shows me the same image. I don't know why. Here is my code :

````
    def recaptcha_de_wish(self):
        ac  = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
        a = random.choice(ac)
        b = random.choice(ac)
        c = random.choice(ac)
        d = random.choice(ac)
        f = random.choice(ac)
        g = random.choice(ac)
        h = random.choice(ac)
        random_string = a + b + c + d + f + g + h
        image  =  ImageCaptcha(width=100, height=90)
        image_1 = image.generate_image(random_string)
        ab = '.png'
        random_source = random_string + '.png'
        string = StringProperty(random_source) 
        print(random_source)
        image_1 = image_1.save(random_source)
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title= "Recaptcha",
                text="Just copy the text you're seeing",
                type="custom",
                content_cls= FitImage(
                    size_hint_y= None,
                    source=random_source,
                    height= "200dp",
                ),
            )
        self.dialog.open()
    ```
````

Comment: When I print the random_string it's everytime a different string but it shows the same image

Comment: Are  you resetting `self.dialog` to `None` anywhere?